# Google Vision API java client: how to set API credentials explicitly in code(without using environment variable)

Tags: java, credentials, google-vision, explicit, client-library

I'm trying to integrate my project with [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries)

Here is the maven dependency for you to check the client version I'm trying to integrate with:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
   <version>1.51.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The way the documentation offers to set the API authentication credentials is the following:

```
Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the 
file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to set the credentials explicitly in code as that is more convenient than setting environment variables in each and every environment we are running our project on.

As I know for a former client version `1.22` that was possible doing the following:

```
def credentialFile = this.class.classLoader
.getResource(grailsApplication.config.credentialsFile)
GoogleCredential credential = 
GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialFile.openStream())
        .createScoped(grailsApplication.config.googleScope)

Vision vision = new 
Vision.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), 
jsonFactory, credential).build()
```

But for the new client API I was not able to find the way and documentation doesn't say anything in that regards.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible any more

Answer (score 2):

It's possible:
Create an ImageAnnotatorSettings like:

```
ImageAnnotatorSettings ias = ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(
                    FixedCredentialsProvider.create(#InputStream of your json key#)
            )
            .build();
```

Add this to your client and voilá!